# Integrating Calendar Widget into QTableView

Tags: python, date, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to open up a calendar widget when a date column is selected in my table view. I have managed to do this but for the fact that when the editing of the cell is finished (user clicked off of cell), the cell shows **PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2021, 1, 1)** instead of **1-Jan-21**.

Date Delegate:

```
class DateDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate): # calender widget
    def __init__(self, owner):
        super().__init__(owner)
        self.table = owner.model()
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        widget = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(parent)         
        widget.setCalendarPopup(True) 
        widget.setDate(datetime.datetime.strptime(self.table.data(index), "%d-%b-%y"))
        return widget
```

MainWindow:

```
self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
self.model = PandasModel(self.dataframe)
self.view.setModel(self.model)
self.view.setItemDelegateForColumn(13,DateDelegate(self.view))
```

PandasModel:

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    """
    Class to populate a table view with a pandas dataframe
    """
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = np.array(data.values)
        self._cols = data.columns
        self.r, self.c = np.shape(self._data)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self.r

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self.c

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
                value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()] 
                if isinstance(value, NaTType): # NaTType given to Date strings that can't be converted to pandas Timestamp
                    return ""
                if isinstance(value, datetime.date):
                    return value.strftime("%d-%b-%y")
                if isinstance(value, float):
                    return int(value)
                
                return str(value)

            if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
                if self._data[index.row()][18].upper() == "PASS":       # Highlight passes as green
                    green = QtGui.QColor(43,235,101)
                    return QtGui.QBrush(green)
                elif self._data[index.row()][18].upper() == "FAIL":     # Failures
                    red = QtGui.QColor(255,75,75)
                    return QtGui.QBrush(red)
                elif self._data[index.row()][18].upper() == "F.E.A.":
                    cyan = QtGui.QColor(40,208,191)
                    return QtGui.QBrush(cyan)
                elif self._data[index.row()][24]:               # Cancelled
                    return QtGui.QBrush(Qt.lightGray)
                elif not isinstance(self._data[index.row()][30], NaTType):
                    if self._data[index.row()][16] > datetime.datetime.today():    # Late to Finish (Planned Finish)
                        darkPink = QtGui.QColor(225,40,126)
                        return QtGui.QBrush(darkPink)
                elif not isinstance(self._data[index.row()][15], NaTType):
                    if self._data[index.row()][15] < datetime.datetime.today():    # In progress (DateStarted)
                        orange = QtGui.QColor(255,211,63)
                        return QtGui.QBrush(orange)     
                elif not isinstance(self._data[index.row()][29], NaTType):
                    if self._data[index.row()][29] > datetime.datetime.today():    # Late to Start (Planned Start)
                        pink = QtGui.QColor(255,163,175)
                        return QtGui.QBrush(pink)                      
        else:
            return False       
        
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            #print(value)
            return True
        
    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable|Qt.ItemIsEnabled|Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def headerData(self, p_int, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return self._cols[p_int]
            elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                return p_int
        return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming that the conversion of QDate to string or datetime is implicit and it is not, therefore you must override the setEditorData and setModelData methods:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

DATE_FORMAT = "%d-%b-%y"


class DateDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        widget = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(parent)
        widget.setCalendarPopup(True)
        return widget

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QDateEdit):
            dt_str = index.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            dt = datetime.strptime(dt_str, DATE_FORMAT)
            editor.setDate(dt)
            return
        super().setEditorData(editor, index)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QDateEdit):
            dt = editor.date().toPyDate()
            model.setData(index, dt, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            return
        super().setModelData(editor, model, index)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much.